# Pandas convert dictionary to datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert mongo data into pandas and I have a field that is in dates and when I convert that data my column field show the value like:

```
0    {'$date': 1616573566159}
1    {'$date': 1616573566159}
2    {'$date': 1616573570647}
3    {'$date': 1616573570647}
```

I can access the value using df['updatedAt'][0]['$date'] is there any by which I can convert all the values to datetime without using loop.

I want to do something like this:

```
df["newTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["updatedAt"])
```

I am converting the values using:

```
for i in range(len(df["updatedAt"])):
    df["newTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["updatedAt"][i]['$date'], unit='ms')
```

Is it possible to do it without loop?

Comment: Do you want to access the data as df['updatedAt'][0] rather than df['updatedAt'][0]['$date'] as well?

Comment: Both works fine for me I am using this code to convert:     for i in range(len(df["updatedAt"])):
        df["newTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["updatedAt"][i]['$date'], unit='ms')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.get`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html) with [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'update': [{'$date': 1616573566159},{'$date': 1616573566159},{'$date': 1616573570647},{'$date': 1616573570647}]})
```

---

```
df["newTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["update"].str.get('$date'), unit='ms')
print (df)
                     update                 newTime
0  {'$date': 1616573566159} 2021-03-24 08:12:46.159
1  {'$date': 1616573566159} 2021-03-24 08:12:46.159
2  {'$date': 1616573570647} 2021-03-24 08:12:50.647
3  {'$date': 1616573570647} 2021-03-24 08:12:50.647
```

Comment: I don't think I've used `pd.Series.str.get`.  Hmmm, I think I'll start (-:

Comment: I am getting '<=' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'

Comment: @NilaySingh - So data are different? What is `print (df["update"].head(10).to_dict())` ?

Comment: Sorry it is working I was grouping something in between.

Answer (score 2):

#### `json_normalize`/`to_datetime`

```
pd.to_datetime(pd.json_normalize(df['update'])['$date'], unit='ms')

0   2021-03-24 08:12:46.159
1   2021-03-24 08:12:46.159
2   2021-03-24 08:12:50.647
3   2021-03-24 08:12:50.647
Name: $date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```